# How to achieve TRY_CONVERT functionality in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, expression, derived-column

In SSIS package I have derived column in which I want to format phone like below:

```
CASE
    WHEN TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, phone) IS NULL THEN
        NULL
    ELSE
        phone
END
```

How can I use the SSIS expression to achieve same result as above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Derived Column

You have to use the following expression:

```
(DT_I8)[Phone] == (DT_I8)[Phone] ? [Phone] : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

**Note that you have to replace `(DT_WSTR,50)` with the data type of column `[Phone]`.** *[Click here for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/null-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)*

And in the derived column error output change the on error option to `Ignore Failure`

[image]

### Script Component

You can also achieve this using a script component:

1. Add a script component to the data flow task
2. Select [Phone] as Input Column
3. Create a new Output Column of the same type of [Phone] example [outPhone]
4. Use a similar code

   ```
   if(!Row.Phone_IsNull && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Phone) && Int64.TryParse(Row.Phone, out long number)){

       Row.OutPhone = Row.Phone;

   }else{

       Row.OutPhone_IsNull = true;

   }
   ```

Comment: It's making NULL for all the values of Phone.

Comment: What is the type of the source column?

Comment: Check that [Phone] doesn't contains unwanted characters or additional spaces

Comment: @JayDesai the try convert logic is 100% correct you must check the data

Comment: Phone column does contain some values with unwanted characters or additional spaces. And that's the reason I want to make it NULL. If it is convertible to BIGINT it should pass it as it is. Source column Phone is coming from csv file and Destination column has BIGINT data type.

Comment: TRY_CONVERT function is working correctly I need the same functionality in SSIS.

Comment: @JayDesai what is the column data type in SSIS? Check it from the flat file connection manager

Comment: @JayDesai does numbers contains a seperator in csv?

Comment: @JayDesai i updated my answer and provided a new method check it out

Comment: @JayDesai also it is better to provide sample data and to add some screenshot of the flat file connection manager