# SSIS task integer not redirect from varchar column as bad data

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, ssis, etl

[image]

I am doing SSIS Error Handling.
In excel file source have four columns id,name,department,salary.
Id and salary (integer column are fine detect varchar datatype and redirect into bad data entry) but name and department(varchar column consider integer and string both values in good data table)?

We want redirect integer values from name and department column to bad data entry

In data conversion transformation configure error output tab to "Redirect" all four rows.Integer datatype (Id and Salary) working fine throw var-char value into bad data table but Va-char datatype column (Name and department) do not throw integer value into bad data table .

[image]

Could any one please help me this issue?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Data Conversion Transformation  editor, Go to `Configure Error Output` and set the error handling option to `Redirect Row`.

For more information, you can refer to the following articles:

- [Error Handling in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/error-handling-in-ssis/)
- [Configure an Error Output in a Data Flow Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/configure-an-error-output-in-a-data-flow-component?view=sql-server-2014)
- [ERROR HANDLING IN SSIS WITH AN EXAMPLE STEP BY STEP](http://www.learnmsbitutorials.net/ssis-error-handling.php)

---

### Update 1

If you are looking to extract numeric values from varchar column you must use a derived column to check if it conatins numeric value and redirect row based on result:

- [How to achieve TRY_CONVERT functionality in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55482719/how-to-achieve-try-convert-functionality-in-ssis/55482819#55482819)

*Example*

```
(DT_I8)[Name] == (DT_I8)[Name] ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : [Name]
```

The error output will contains non numeric values. The main output will contains numbers.

Comment: Thanks for replying.But i have all ready configured Data conversion error output tab to 'Redirect" for all four rows.Integer column(Id and Salary) are working fine they throw all var-char value  into bad data table and integer value into good data table  but Var-char Column(Name and department) do not throw any integer value to bad data table...all data goes to good data table.....Hope so i have expained the issue

Comment: @Ankush feel free to mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the mark on the left side of the answer

Comment: Marked as useful and resolved problem @Hadi...once again thanks a lot.